# Monotone likelihood property and first order stochastic dominance

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a question regarding first order stochastic dominance.

Give two pdf $f(x)$, $g(x)$, $x\in[x_0,x_1]$. For all $x$ on the support, I have
$$
g(x) = f(x)\cdot H(x)
$$
where $H(x)$ is continuous, decreasing and strictly positive.

Is it sufficient to show that $f$ FOSD $g$? If not, what other conditions do I need?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fully solved on WP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_likelihood_ratio#First-order_stochastic_dominance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is related to monotone likelihood ratios $-$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_likelihood_ratio $-$ which does imply FOSD.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Helps a lot!